# Insert, Update error: Subquery returned more than 1 row in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a SQL script in stored procedure and query by C#.

But it throws an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

As I know the problem is that the subquery is returning more than one row to the main query. May I know how to solve it? Thank you.

```
public void insertData(string TransID, string Item, string FromLocation, string Qty, string Requestor, string RefNum, string Remark, string ReasonID, string ReasonRemark, string CreateDate, string CreateUser, string ToLocation)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection _cn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("MMSIssue_InsertOrUpdate", _cn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
            {
                _cn.Open();

                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_TRANS_ID", TransID);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_ID", Item);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_LOCATION", FromLocation);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_QTY", Qty);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR", Requestor);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_TRANS_REFNO", RefNum);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_TRANS_REMARK", Remark);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_REASON_ID", ReasonID);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_REASON_REMARK", ReasonRemark);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_CREATE_DATE", CreateDate);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_CREATE_USER", CreateUser);
                _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INV_FROMLOC", ToLocation);

                _cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordFound", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
                _cmd.Parameters["@RecordFound"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string DeleteWMMRSQL = "DELETE FROM [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[OTH_INV_QTY_LOC] WHERE INV_QTY = 0 OR INV_QTY is null OR INV_QTY <= '-1'";

                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(DeleteWMMRSQL, _cn);
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                _cn.Close();

                float INV_QTY = Convert.ToInt32(_cmd.Parameters["@RecordFound"].Value.ToString());

                if (INV_QTY == 2)
                {
                    //QTY is more Than existing QTY !!"); 
                    Response.Write("QTY is more Than existing QTY !!");
                    Response.Redirect("MMS_LocationTrans.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    //QTY not able to key in 0
                    Response.Write("QTY not able to key in 0!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MMSIssue_InsertOrUpdate] 
    @INV_TRANS_ID VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_ID VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_LOCATION VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_QTY FLOAT,
    @INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_TRANS_REFNO VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_TRANS_REMARK VARCHAR(255),
    @INV_REASON_ID VARCHAR(40),
    @INV_REASON_REMARK VARCHAR(255),
    @INV_CREATE_DATE DATETIME,
    @INV_CREATE_USER VARCHAR (255),
    @INV_FROMLOC VARCHAR (40),
    @RecordFound INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
              WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE OTH_INV_QTY_LOC 
        SET [INV_ID] = @INV_ID,
            INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION, 
            INV_QTY = INV_QTY - @INV_QTY 
        WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID 
          AND INV_LOCATION = @INV_LOCATION

        INSERT INTO OTH_INV_TRANSACTION (INV_TRANS_ID, INV_ID, INV_TRANS_LOCATION, INV_TRANS_QTY, INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR, INV_TRANS_REFNO, INV_TRANS_REMARK, INV_REASON_ID, INV_REASON_REMARK, INV_CREATE_DATE, INV_CREATE_USER, INV_FROMLOC)
        VALUES (@INV_TRANS_ID, @INV_ID, @INV_LOCATION, @INV_QTY, @INV_TRANS_REQUESTOR, @INV_TRANS_REFNO, @INV_TRANS_REMARK, @INV_REASON_ID, @INV_REASON_REMARK, @INV_CREATE_DATE, @INV_CREATE_USER, @INV_FROMLOC)

        DECLARE @InvFindQTY FLOAT 
        SET @InvFindQTY = (SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC)

        IF @InvFindQTY >= @INV_QTY 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @RecordFound = 2
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @RecordFound = 1
        END
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RecordFound = 0
    END
END
```

Comment: Because you didn't provide your stored procedure so I can't tell what exactly is your problem. If you think your sub query returned more than one result to your main query, you can try to limit the result that is returned by sub query by using `select top 1` to see if that really is the issue

Comment: Run your subquery on it's own and look at the results.  Decide which one you want.  Write the code to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line in the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE  @InvFindQTY FLOAT 
SET @InvFindQTY = ( SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC)
```

If you have more than one record in OTH_INV_QTY_LOC, you will receive this error.

It looks like you should be able to fix the problem by adding

```
WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID
```

to ensure that only a single record is selected, i.e.:

```
SET @InvFindQTY = ( SELECT INV_QTY FROM OTH_INV_QTY_LOC WHERE INV_ID = @INV_ID)
```

Comment: very very thanks bro.i had search most of post but not resolve.